# Is there way to use extension methods to achieve below implementation in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method which does something like shown below :

```
// check if bits 6,7,8 are zero
if ((num >> 5) != 0)
{
    //do some thing
    return false;
}

// check if bits 2 ,3,4 are zero
if ((num & 0x0E) != 0)
{
     //do something
     return false;
}

// check if bit 1 is 1
if ((num & 1) != 1)
{
    //dosomething
    return false;
 }
```

and now I want to add extension method like :

```
   num
   .arebitsset((6,7,8) ,(do some action and return from method if false , if true allow chaining))
   .arebitsset(2,3,4) , <same as above>)
   .......
```

While I know the logic for bitset checking, but I need to know how to return from the method or allow chaining based on true/false outcome.

Is it possible by using func? I am not sure.

**NOTE : I have 80 such conditions to be tested below , so is it good to write 80 if conditions , certainly not , so i need some compact form**

Comment: How complex would be acceptable? It can be done, but it would be a lot of boilerplate code and it would be very unintuitive because normally it does not work that way. It might be easier to read if you just had an extension method to return true/false and then did the `if`s yourself.

Comment: @nvoigt i can hide the domain logic but i need the readablity and simplicity on client side , so i need the signature what i wrote above

Comment: I think that monads offer something similar to what you want. You might want to read about them. However, thay are not natural to C# so you might just write `flatMap` / `bind` operation.

Comment: A function of signature `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` in Haskell's notation

Comment: @GrayCat but i need it in c#

Comment: Are you always going to check if three bits are set, or is it a variable number.  Your notation (you start with `num` and then call a function based on it and then call a function based on the return value) doesn't match your description.  If `AreBitsSet` returns a Boolean, then you can't call another `AreBitsSet` on the return value.  Also, does the action your want to perform always have the same signature?  If so, what is it?

Comment: 1) if ((num & 0xE0) == 0xE0) 2) if ((num & 0x0E) == 0x0E)

Comment: @Flydog57 i might check three or variable i have that logic in place , my main problem is but I need to know how to return from the method or allow chaining based on true/false outcome.

Comment: It's easy to write an extension method that looks like `public static bool AreBitsSet(this int number, params int[] bitNumbers)` and then use that in `if` statements.  But, I don't quite see how you'd do what you are trying to specify (or, I'm misunderstanding what you are asking)

Comment: 80 conditions?  If this is just a byte (highest bit is 8), then I'd just make a function table array.

Comment: @RobertMcKee its one byte of big NR ( 5G)  Frame

Comment: Then just make an array of functions (256 functions) and skip the bit manipulation.

Comment: @RobertMcKee sorry i did not get your idea , and also i need readability

Comment: Just put the idea into an answer for you since the code is a bit long for a comment.

Comment: You cannot return from the middle of a method chain. You could mimick this behaviour, but that would be awful...

Comment: @LaurentGabiot so please suggest a nice method ?

Comment: You mean not using extension method at all?

Comment: @LaurentGabiot you are free to use whatever you want , but i need a compact readable solution ,

Comment: Honestly, if readablity is the goal, I think the original code using ifs is quite readable, and the other solutions I could think about seems less readable to me.

Comment: but do you want me to write 80 if conditions ?

Answer (score 6):

You could write extension methods like this:

```
public static class BitSetExtensions
{
    private static bool AreBitsSet(int i, int[] bits)
    {
        // you already have this
    }

    public static (int value, bool valid) CallActionIfBitsSet(this int value, int[] bits, Action action)
    {
        return CallActionIfBitsSet((value, true), bits, action);
    }

    public static (int value, bool valid) CallActionIfBitsSet(this (int value, bool valid) data, int[] bits, Action action)
    {
        if (data.valid)
        {
            data.valid = AreBitsSet(data.value, bits);

            if (data.valid) action();
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

Then you can chain them like this:

```
int num = 5;

num.CallActionIfBitsSet(new[] {1, 3, 5}, () =>
    {
        /* action */
    })
    .CallActionIfBitsSet(new[] {2, 3, 4}, () =>
    {
        /* other action */
    })
    .CallActionIfBitsSet(new[] {2, 3, 6}, () =>
    {
        /* other action */
    });
```

I am not a big fan personally because I don't think your interface gets easier this way compared to traditional `if`, but it would work.

Comment: Rather than using an array as a parameter, use a `params` array.

Comment: @nvoigt i have approached this way , but where in your code exactly you are returning from the main function , i mean if first condition is wrong i should not exectue the chains below , does your code acheive this ?

Comment: @Flydog57 That only works if it's the last parameter and it's not supposed to be :(

Comment: @KeshavRaghav Ah... yes? I'm not "returning" because that's technically not possible, but the first check in the function basically skips all chained calls if one return value was false.

Comment: @nvoigt but in a true sense i should exit from the method , the method might have few more things to do after this chaining , which should not be executed , so do you think it is not possible in c# this way

Comment: You cannot "exit" from a method chain (well, you could throw an Exception, but then it gets really weird if your goal is to "simplify"). Not in C# and not in any other language I know. Do you have any language in mind where it would indeed work that way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205460/discussion-between-keshav-raghav-and-nvoigt).

Comment: You seem to be missing the `this` keyword on your extension methods.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway It should be right there: `this int value`.

Comment: @nvoigt - My bad.  I didn't recognize that you were returning a tuple.  I saw the parentheses and assumed that was the start of the method arguments.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to achieve something that should be ok for you.

You can define structure as in code below. Using pattern matching and basing on monads, specifically on `flatMap` function with signature that you can see below, it is possible to create a chain of functions that would stop executing completelty transparent to the caller, based only on what happens inside those functions.

You can read more about it if you search for Rust's `Option` or Haskell's `Maybe`. Those types (*sum types*) that those languages use are not however native to C#, they need some effort to implement.

For example in code below only

> 1 2 2 I got None!

Will be displayed to console as third call to `FlatMap` breaks the chain returning `None`.

This can be used to your particular problem, however it can be also used to a lot of other problems.

By inspecting type of final value you can learn if the chain of calls was succesfull.

The pro of this approach is that all `ifs` are completely transparent to the caller.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var a = new Option<int>.Some(1);
        var result = a.FlatMap<int>(i => { Console.WriteLine(i); return new Option<int>.Some(i + 1); })
         .FlatMap<int>(i => { Console.WriteLine(i); return new Option<int>.Some(i); })
         .FlatMap<int>(i => { Console.WriteLine(i); return new Option<int>.None(); })
         .FlatMap<int>(i => { Console.WriteLine(i); return new Option<int>.Some(i); });

        switch (result)
        {
            case Option<int>.Some some:
                Console.WriteLine("I got Some!");
                break;
            case Option<int>.None none:
                Console.WriteLine("I got None!");
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

    }
}

public abstract class Option<T>
{
    public class Some : Option<T>
    {
        public Some(T data)
        {
            Data = data;
        }

        public T Data;
    }

    public class None : Option<T> { }

    public Option<T> FlatMap<T>(Func<T, Option<T>> action)
    {
        switch (this)
        {
            case Option<T>.Some some:
                return action(some.Data);
            case Option<T>.None none:
                return none;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but then if i have 80 conditions why should i execute all if the first one it self fails ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return from the middle of a method chain.
You could invent a way to mimick such a behaviour but it would be not so nice, as one reading the method call alone would not suspect such a behaviour.

Since you also asked for this in comment, an alternative method if you want to avoid the 80 "if"s not using extension methods would be to have a list of pair of test and action to perform if the test is successful, test each in a foreach loop.
I don't think you would gain any readability, but there would be only one "if" in your code.

Using a simple class like this one (alternatively, ValueTupple could be used to get rid of this class):

```
public class Test
{
    public Func<int, bool> Condition { get; set; }
    public Func<int, bool> Operation { get; set; }
}
```

You could do:

```
    var Tests = new List<Test>
    {
        new Test
        {
            Condition = num => (num >> 5) != 0,
            Operation = num => { // Do stuff}
        },
        new Test
        {
            Condition = num => (num & 0x0E) != 0,
            Operation = num => { // Do other stuff}
        }
        // Add all your 80+ tests here
    };

// Then use a single if:
foreach (var test in Tests)
{
    if(test.Condition(Number))
    {
        test.Operation(Number);
        // Whatever the test that succeeded was, do here what you need to perform before returning, if needed.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without throwing big words like monads around, you can construct an object representing the entire execution plan and then short-circuit it from the inside. It'd be very akin to making your own LINQ method, only instead of enumerating the source and then yielding the results, we need to be able to run the plan or extend it (continue) with another action. Our `IExecutable<T>` will represent a chain of actions dependent on a parameter of type `T` that can be executed, returning a status that allows other methods in the chain to modify the control flow as needed. We'll need a unary parameter and parameterless version:

```cs
public enum ExecutionResult
{
    RunToCompletion,
    Aborted
}

public interface IExecutable
{
    ExecutionResult Execute();
}

public interface IExecutable<T>
{
    ExecutionResult Execute(T argument);
}
```

We'll make two (technically three) implementations. First, a `SimpleExecutable` and `SimpleExecutable<T>`, that won't do any fancy stuff, just wrap an action and run it.

```cs
internal class SimpleExecutable : IExecutable
{
    private readonly Func<ExecutionResult> _action;

    public SimpleExecutable(Func<ExecutionResult> action) => _action = action;

    public ExecutionResult Execute() => _action();
}

internal class SimpleExecutable<T> : IExecutable<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, ExecutionResult> _action;

    public SimpleExecutable(Func<T, ExecutionResult> action) => _action = action;

    public ExecutionResult Execute(T argument) => _action(argument);
}
```

Nothing interesting here, now the one you actually want, a `ShortCircuitingConditionalExecutable<T>`:

```cs
internal class ShortCircuitingConditionalExecutable<T> : IExecutable<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, ExecutionResult> _action;
    private readonly Func<T, bool> _predicate;

    public ShortCircuitingConditionalExecutable(
        Func<T, ExecutionResult> action,
        Func<T, bool> predicate) =>
        (_action, _predicate) = (action, predicate);

    public ExecutionResult Execute(T argument)
    {
        if (!_predicate(argument))
        {
            return ExecutionResult.Aborted;
        }

        _action(argument);
        return ExecutionResult.RunToCompletion;
    }
}
```

`Execute` checks the predicate, runs the method if it's true and returns a result signalling whether we should short-circuit the operation.

To make this more handy to use, let's make a few helper extensions:

```cs
public static class Executable
{
    public static IExecutable<T> StartWithIf<T>(
        Action<T> action,
        Func<T, bool> predicate) =>
        new ShortCircuitingConditionalExecutable<T>(ReturnCompletion(action), predicate);

    public static IExecutable ContinueWith(this IExecutable source, IExecutable executable) =>
        new SimpleExecutable(ChainIfCompleted(source.Execute, executable.Execute));

    public static IExecutable<T> ContinueWith<T>(this IExecutable<T> source, IExecutable<T> executable) =>
        new SimpleExecutable<T>(ChainIfCompleted<T>(source.Execute, executable.Execute));

    public static IExecutable<T> ContinueWithIf<T>(
        this IExecutable<T> source,
        Action<T> action,
        Func<T, bool> predicate) =>
        source.ContinueWith(new ShortCircuitingConditionalExecutable<T>(ReturnCompletion(action), predicate));

    public static IExecutable BindArgument<T>(this IExecutable<T> source, T argument) =>
        new SimpleExecutable(() => source.Execute(argument));

    private static Func<ExecutionResult> ChainIfCompleted(
        Func<ExecutionResult> action1,
        Func<ExecutionResult> action2) =>
        () =>
        {
            var result = action1();
            return result != ExecutionResult.RunToCompletion ? result : action2();
        };

    private static Func<T, ExecutionResult> ChainIfCompleted<T>(
        Func<T, ExecutionResult> action1,
        Func<T, ExecutionResult> action2) =>
        t =>
        {
            var result = action1(t);
            return result != ExecutionResult.RunToCompletion ? result : action2(t);
        };

    private static Func<T, ExecutionResult> ReturnCompletion<T>(Action<T> action) =>
        t =>
        {
            action(t);
            return ExecutionResult.RunToCompletion;
        };
}
```

I've omitted a few obvious extensions we could make, but that's rather a lot of code, so maybe a motivating example of this thing in action:

```cs
class Program
{
    private static Func<int, bool> AreBitsSet(params int[] bits) => 
       n => bits.All(b => (n & (1 << b)) != 0);

    private static void Print(int n) => Console.WriteLine(n);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var num1 = (1 << 2) | (1 << 4) | (1 << 5);
        var num2 = num1 | (1 << 7);

        var executable = Executable.StartWithIf(Print, AreBitsSet(2))
            .ContinueWithIf(Print, AreBitsSet(2, 4, 5))
            .ContinueWithIf(Print, AreBitsSet(7));

        var executableNum1 = executable.BindArgument(num1);
        var executableNum2 = executable.BindArgument(num2);

        var program = executableNum1.ContinueWith(executableNum2);

        executable.Execute(num1);
        executable.Execute(num2);
        program.Execute();
    }
}
```

The first execution prints `52` twice (`num1`). The second execution prints `180` thrice (`num2`). The execution of `program` prints only `52` twice and short-circuits the rest of the execution.

This is not a fully production-ready module, as I've ignored argument validation and there are probably possible optimisations that would avoid some allocations when constructing the execution flow (we're making a lot of delegates). Also, it would be really nice to make this thing more fluent by enabling `execution.ContinueWith(action).If(predicate)` syntax. It's also terribly overcomplicated, since your use case requires only a very specific execution chain, but what the heck, it was fun writing it up.

Aside: To anyone interested, this is not a monad, but very close so. We would have to replace `Execute` with something that returns the constructed `Action<T>` delegate and then write up the appropriate `bind` function. Then we'd get a monad over `Action`s of any `T`, and we could still make `Execute` into an extension method that gets the delegate and immediately calls it. The `BindArgument` is a special case of a `bind`: `t => bind(e, f => () => f(t))`.

Comment: after the first call fails , it should never execute any method below , for example in your code : executable.Execute(num1);
        executable.Execute(num2);     once execute num1 fails on any condtion execute(num2) should not execute at all

Comment: @KeshavRaghav Didn't notice. Edited my answer to accomodate that use case. Required me to add the return status, cause I'm pretty sure you can't do it without that.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the conditions with an [`if`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) statement is the most efficient and the easiest to debug. In case of an exception you'll know where to look for the bug. My only suggestion is to get rid of the recurrent `return false;` statements, by using a single `if` with multiple `else if`:

```
public static bool Execute(int num)
{
    if ((num >> 5) != 0) // check if bits 6, 7, 8 are zero
    {
        // do something
    }
    else if ((num & 0x0E) != 0) // check if bits 2, 3, 4 are zero
    {
        // do something
    }
    else if ((num & 1) != 1) // check if bit 1 is 1
    {
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        return false; // nothing has been done
    }
    return true; // something has been done
}
```